# how do I get a function loaded into the SmTbl.c?

Tags: command-line, vxworks

I'm wrorking on a project and woudl like to call a function I just wrote from the VxWorks command line and I believe, to be able to do so, I need to get it loaded into `SymTbl.c` but I'm wondering how I can get this achieved as that file is being created automatically on every build. On top of the file it says:`CREATED BY C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/host/resource/hutils/tcl/makeSymTbl.tcl1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough information to really help you, but I am going to guess you have the following situation:

1. Running vxworks
2. A standalone vxworks module with your function in it

If this is the case then you can just load the module with the ld vxworks command, and then just call the function from the command line.

A few things to note, if your function is static then you will not be able to call it, and if it is c++ then you may need to create a C interface to it...

Look in the docs for usrLib to read more about the ld command, I would link to it, but I don't know where to find good VxWorks docs online anymore...